# parsing character error in SQL via XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-parsing, special-characters

I have the below code which errors when I run it because it has the "&" sign and can not convert it.

the result should display "testing &". however if I change the xml bit to "testing &" it works. I need a way to replace it so that it does not error.

```
Declare @Request XML = null
If @Request IS NULL 
BEGIN
    SET @Request = '
                    <Request>  
                       <ProductRequest>
                    <ProductName>testing &</ProductName>
                      </ProductRequest>
                     </Request>'
END 

select @Request.value ('(//ProductName)[1]','nvarchar(100)')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for this:

```
Declare @Request XML = null
If @Request IS NULL 
BEGIN
    SET @Request = (SELECT 'testing &' AS ProductName FOR XML PATH('ProductRequest'),ROOT('Request'));
END 

select @Request.value ('(//ProductName)[1]','nvarchar(100)')
```

Some background:

**XML is more than just some text with extra characters**. XML should never be generated just by typing (as in your case) or by string concatenation (often seen). Use the **proper method to *generate* your XML** and all encoding issues are solved for you implicitly.

Look at the XML generated and you will find, that the `&` is found as `&amp;`. While reading this with `value()` the re-encoding is done for you - again implicitly.

You should not start to do own `REPLACE` approaches. Next day someone enters a `<`or `>` or another not supported character and you have the same troubles again.

Answer (score 1):

The `&` is a reserved/special character in XML. It should be &amp ; and remove space between &amp and ;

as the next:

```
Declare @Request XML = null
If @Request IS NULL 
BEGIN
    SET @Request = '
                    <Request>  
                       <ProductRequest>
                    <ProductName>testing &amp;</ProductName>
                      </ProductRequest>
                     </Request>'
END 

select @Request.value ('(//ProductName)[1]','nvarchar(100)')
```

Comment: I need something to replace "&" with "&amp;" automatically, as the user will only enter & in the productname area

Comment: I'd strongly advise not even to think about entity references. This is something done for you implicitly, if you just use `SELECT ... FOR XML ...` When you deal with XML one should avoid to think *in string*...

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the entity reference `&amp;` in the XML string for the ampersand:

```
DECLARE @Request XML = NULL;
IF @Request IS NULL 
BEGIN
    SET @Request = '
                    <Request>  
                       <ProductRequest>
                    <ProductName>testing &amp;</ProductName>
                      </ProductRequest>
                     </Request>';
END; 

SELECT @Request.value ('(//ProductName)[1]','nvarchar(100)');
```

See [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references](http://List%20of%20XML%20and%20HTML%20character%20entity%20references)

Comment: I'd strongly advise not even to think about entity references. This is something done for you implicitly, if you just use `SELECT ... FOR XML ...` When you deal with XML one should avoid to think *in string*...

Comment: @Shnugo, agreed entity references are transparent when XML objects and methods are used, but that is not the case here since the string was created manually.